# Vim airline plugin orange arrow bug

Tags: vim, fonts, vim-plugins

I have the airline plugin installed for vim and no matter which theme I pick there is always an orange arrow in the bottom right corner of the screen. How can I fix this?

[image: Orange arrow, bottom right corner]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is no error, but the expected behaviour, because the last section is empty. If you don't want that behaviour, see the help for the `skip_empty` variable.

Comment: Thanks, after looking up the help for skip_empty it seems to be intended behavior for airline. However it can be fixed by disabling the whitespace/indent checking.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, add this to your vimrc: `let airline#extensions#whitespace#enabled = 0`

Comment: that does a different thing.

Comment: Care to elaborate what different thing that does? It achieves the intended result but maybe it has an unintended consequence that I'm not aware of.

Comment: You are disabling the whitespace extension. That does not necessarily disable the orange triangle.

Comment: It does disable the orange triangle. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The better way to solve it is to use the `skip_empty` variable, as I have written.

Comment: You've told me to see the help for the `skip_empty` variable, however you have not actually given me the answer. I'm all for RTFM but unfortunately I did read the help entry for `skip_empty` and still do not understand it. Could you please elaborate on how I should use the `skip_empty` variable to disable the orange arrow?